# How to mark first and last value with pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a 3D plot, which I want to mark the first and last value in special way (for example: triangle or circle):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax.plot(x,y,z)
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

I want to mark the first and last dot / value in plot with triangle or circle.
How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a scatter plot with your 2 values.

```
ax.scatter(xs[0], ys[0], zs[0], c=c, marker=m)
```